# sweetalert2 con php error Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

Tags: javascript, php7

Estoy iniciando en la programación web con php.
Tengo un proyecto en cual muestro los mensajes del sistema con sweetalert2, lo venia usando muy bien (funcionaba correctamente) lo imprimía con un echo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando lo imprimo se sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se sale en el html:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente imprimir desde javascript con una función pero me sale `Uncaught ReferenceError myFunction() is not defined.`
Pueden ayudarme por favor..
De antemano muchas gracias..

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. En vez de las imágenes por favor pon el texto con el código y el texto con los mensajes de error que recibes. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/231647/edit) para hacerlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estas importando la librería de SweetAlert antes de ejecutar el mensaje?

```js
function MuestraAlert(){
  swal("Titulo", "Prueba", "success");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="MuestraAlert()">Boton Sweet</button>
```

Casi siempre el problema es por que tratas de ejecutar el método antes de importar la librería

Saludos

Comment: Aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se realizan como comentario, revisar [answer].